# My json encoded PHP data is not being showed in JavaScript despite being echoed out

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php 

$eventJSON = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM drop_event WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$count = $statement->rowCount();

if($count > 0){
  foreach($result as $row){
     array_push($eventJSON, $row);
  }
}

$eventJSON = json_encode($eventJSON);
//The data is being printed
print_r($eventJSON);
?>

<script>
//This is showing an error
/** (SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data) **/
var eventjson = JSON.parse('<?php echo $eventJSON; ?>');
console.log(eventjson);
</script>
```

Comment: Your `json_encode` turns it into a json string, you don't need to `print_r` it simply `print` it.  BTW - your post was unreadable, I made an edit adding code formatting.

Comment: thanks a lot ivanivan. but can't the javascript eventjson variable be shown in the console after being parsed?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You already prepare the statement, but you need to parameterize it too!. Otherwise you are following [cargo cult](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement)

Comment: Why do you need `if($count > 0){`? It serves no purpose here.

Comment: count there is more like num_rows > 0, finding the number of affected rows